# How to make full join between 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Table "DATES" contains days:

```sql
select * from dates;
```

```
click_date
------------
2019-08-14
2019-08-04
2019-07-24
```

Table "Clicks" contains date,clicker,click:

```sql
select date,clicker,click_count 
from Clicks;
```

```
   date    | clicker | click_count
-----------------------------------
2019-08-04 | 3422    |           2
2019-07-24 | 3539    |           7
```

I need to get all clicker and click_count for all dates:

```
    date    | clicker | click_count
------------------------------------
 2019-08-04 | 3422    |           2
 2019-08-14 | 3422    |           0
 2019-07-24 | 3422    |           0
 2019-08-04 | 3539    |           0
 2019-08-14 | 3539    |           0
 2019-07-24 | 3539    |           7
```

please advice.

Koby

Comment: What is the purpose of dates table ? you can get all the information from clicks table itself right ?

Comment: your expected data doesn't make complete sense, How do you know if clicker was `3422` when he didn't have any click count on `2019-08-14`

Answer (score 6):

I would actually use a cross join here, followed by another left join to bring in the click count data:

```
SELECT
    d.click_date,
    c1.clicker,
    COALESCE(c2.click_count, 0) AS click_count
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN Clicks c1
LEFT JOIN Clicks c2
    ON d.click_date = c2.date AND c1.clicker = c2.clicker
ORDER BY
    c1.clicker,
    d.click_date;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: If the `Clicks` table could have a given clicker appearing more than once, then use:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT clicker FROM Clicks) c1
```

to remove duplicates before cross joining.

Comment: Why the complexity?  He wants everything from both listed tables?

Comment: yeah, need `coalse` to, since if do not found any value it would replace with 0

Comment: @brazosFX I don't if you downvoted, but if so, it was mistaken, because this is the only way to handle the OP's requirements, apart maybe from a union query, which however won't scale at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I understand now.  Too quick, you are right.

Comment: @Tim You have applied cross join to get the clicker ?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja The cross join generates the matrix of all known dates and clickers (one row for each combination).  Then, we left join another time to the clicker table to bring in the counts.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, `cte` section is only to get the distinct date, if you already have distinct dates then you may skip this.

```
  ; with cte as (
  select distinct click_date from dates 
  )
  select c.click_date, cl.clicker, case when c.click_date=cl.date then cl.click_count else 0 end as Counts
  from cte as c cross join Clicks as cl 
  order by cl.clicker, c.click_date
```

You only need simple `cross join` to get your desired result, as I understand your issue is all about the `count` column in result. For which `case` condition is sufficient to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Left join could do the needful as below

```
      select d.date, c.clicker, Case 
     when c.click_count IS NULL Then 0
      ELSE c.click_count End 
      from dates d left join clicks c on 
      d.date=c.date;
```

Comment: This would only generate one record containing `2019-08-14`, when clearly the expected output has _two_ rows for this date.  A simple left join is not enough here.

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per date and clicker, so cross join the two. If there is no clickers table, then you can get the clickers from the clicks table. At last outer join the clicks table:

```
select
  dates.click_date,
  clickers.clicker,
  coalesce(clicks.click_count, 0) as clicks_count
from dates
cross join (select distinct clicker from clicks) clickers
left join clicks on clicks.date = dates.date and clicks.clicker = clickers.clicker
order by dates.click_date, clickers.clicker;
```

Comment: Oh, I just saw that Tim had extended his answer to get distinct clickers, long before I wrote this answer. So, it seems my answer doesn't add anything valuable here :-(

Comment: It increases the Stack Overflow answer database size slightly, which probably helps them to go off and get more VC funding.  So, it does serve a purpose ^ ^